# View returns some properties as null to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, web-applications

This is my View:

```
    @model MediaShuttleCoreWebApp.Models.MediaShuttleAPI.ApiResponse.TransferLinkResponseContainer

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "CreateDownloadToken";
}

<h2>CreateDownloadToken</h2>


<div class="container we myBorder">
    <h3 class="text-center display-4 myBorder"> Media Shuttle </h3>
    @if (Model.User == null)
    {

    }
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="@Url.Action("SendEmail","MediaShuttle", Model)"
       role="button">Create Download Token</a>
    <p>Email: @Model.User.Email</p>
</div>
```

Now when the user clicks on the "button" which is an "a tag" it does send the Model back to the controller. However I notice that it return 2 properties as NULL and the rest are populated with the values that was originally pass to the View().

This is the model that is passed to the View():

```
namespace MediaShuttleCoreWebApp.Models.MediaShuttleAPI.ApiResponse
{
[DataContract]
    public class TransferLinkResponseContainer
{        
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "createdOn")]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "expiresOn")]
    public DateTime ExpiresOn { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "user")]
    public User User { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "grants")]
    public IList<string> Grants { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "destinationPath")]
    public string DestinationPath { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "notifications")]
    public IList<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
}
}
```

The 2 properties that are returned as NULL are:

```
public User User { get; set; }
public IList<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
```

Notice that these 2 properties are not your ordinary string,int or datetime type. So the scenario is when i pass the Model from the Controller to the View() i have data, but when I pass the Model from the View() to Controller, in the "Url.Action" only some properties are populated with the original values. Any idea why is this happening? I've looked everywhere but nothing that actually explains why 2 of my properties come back as null.

I thought about just creating a ViewModel that does have these 2 properties of distinct type and setting them as string.

This is the class for User property:

```
    [DataContract]
public class User
{
    [DataMember(Name = "email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

It just holds a string.

Open to any suggestions as well. But i really want to understand what is going on when the Model gets returned to the Controller why these 2 properties come back as null.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in `href` tag. For example I will use only part of your model to show what causes this behavior.

```
public class TransferLinkResponseContainer
{
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public IList<string> Grants { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

And lets instantiate model as following

```
var model = new TransferLinkResponseContainer
{
    Url = "url",
    User = new User
    {
        Email = "test@test.com"
    },
    Grants = new List<string> { "grant1", "grant2" },
};
```

With this setup `href` will contain the following value

```
"/MediaShuttle/SendEmail?Grants=grant1&Grants=grant2&Url=url&User=ASPNETCoreDeploy.Controllers.User"
```

We can see that it contains all `Grants` values, `Url` value and full name of `User` class (it differs in your project). It is obviously an invalid sting to represent `User` object. Model binder cannot bind `User` properties from `"ASPNETCoreDeploy.Controllers.User"` string on request, so that's why `User` is `null`.

Why this happens? Apparently `Url.Action` just calls `ToString` method for every property of passed model (or iterates collections and calls `ToString` for every element). It is possible to override this method but it won't help to properly bind an object. Lets see what happens if we do this. Override `ToString` for `User`

```
public class User
{
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Email;
    }
}
```

and `href` value becomes

```
"/MediaShuttle/SendEmail?Grants=grant1&Grants=grant2&Url=url&User=test@test.com"
```

Looks better but you will get `User` equals `null` anyway. To properly bind `User` object you need to stick with the following template `User.Prop1=val1&User.Prop2=val2...` and so on. In your case the following url will work as expected

```
"/MediaShuttle/SendEmail?Grants=grant1&Grants=grant2&Url=url&User.Email=test@test.com"
```

But it is not possible (as far as I know) to achieve with `Url.Action`. That's why the more preferable way of passing complex objects is using `<form>` tag.